Haproxy 3.0 with PHP-FPM 301 header mangled to 302
I am trying to use HAProxy with an FCGI backend to php-fpm for a redirection service
When I attempt to write a 301 redirect, and check the response with cURL, it's sending a 302 instead of a 301.
Very basic HAProxy config:
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    user haproxy
    group www-data

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout client  50s
    timeout server  50s

frontend myproxy
    bind :80
    default_backend phpservers

backend phpservers
    use-fcgi-app php-fpm
    server server1 127.0.0.1:8080 proto fcgi

fcgi-app php-fpm
    log-stderr global
    docroot /var/www/sites/redirector/
    index redirector.php
    path-info ^(/.+\.php)(/.*)?$

Very basic FPM config:
root@dave:/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d# cat /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/redirector.conf
[redirector]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 8080
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3

Very basic PHP script:
<?php
header("Location: site.test",TRUE,301);

Very annoying response:
# curl -sv -H "Host: 301.com" http://127.0.0.1
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 301.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< location: http://site.test/
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< date: Wed, 26 Jun 2024 05:09:05 GMT
< content-length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact

Attempted simplifying location header, and adding preceding headers for redirection type:
First:
<?php
http_response_code(301);
header('Location: http://site.test/');

Second:
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://site.test/');

